# SSP CLASS IN DATATABLES

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am trying to set up server side script code for DataTables. What I have done so far :

1. Downloaded SSP from package
2. Installed PEARL on PHP server
3. Changed PHP.INI file include_path to the pearl folder
4. Placed the SSP class inside the same folder.

I keep getting the error message :

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '\crm\maintenance\ssp.class.php' (include_path='C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\php\v5.3\pear\') in C:\IIS\CRM\maintenance\khalid.php

Thhis is how i am calling the ssp class

```
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
```

SOME ADVICE!

Answer (score 0):

The above steps WORK.  In editing the question I had noticed that i was trying to specify a path in statement below as such :

```
require( '\xxx\xxxssp.class.php' );  // this does not work
```

FOLLOW the steps as outline the question itself and it will work!